# Answered with error to command 0xa4: Get Vehicle Variable: unsupported variable 0x32 specified

Tags: sumo

I'm trying to retrieve vehicle lateral speed using TraCI with a python script. However, I get the below error when I use the method:

```
C:\Users\xxx\src\sumo-1.2.0\test> python runner.py --nogui
Loading configuration... done.
Step #0.05Error: Answered with error to command 0xa4: Get Vehicle Variable: unsupported variable 0x32 specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .....
traci.exceptions.TraCIException: Get Vehicle Variable: unsupported variable 0x32 specified
Error: tcpip::Socket::recvAndCheck @ recv: peer shutdown
Quitting (on error).
```

This is my sumocfg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/sumoConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <net-file value="net.net.xml"/>
        <additional-files value="vtypes.add.xml,routes.rou.xml,emitt.emi.xml,detect.poi.xml"/>
    </input>

    <time>
        <begin value="0"/>
        <end value="500"/>
        <step-length value="0.05"/>
        <lateral-resolution value="0.3"/>
    </time>

    
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SUMO version is too old. The requested command is only available since 1.3.0.

Comment: I have upgraded to sumo 1.8, and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Please double check that you do not have any old traci packages somewhere in your python path.